# using js-ctypes in extension crashing firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, firefox-addon, shim

I've created the extension that will call native DLL function using js-ctypes. I've written the native DLL(Written in C) and it exports a C function that is called by extension javascript. I am trying to load another DLL (written in c++) from my native DLL.

My problem is that if I install the extension, Firefox is crashing on launch.

Please help me to fix the problem.

Comment: code is pretty simple, i'm passing some browser data to DLL from extension.

if i include LoadLibrary() function to load other DLL in the native DLL, its crashing. if i comment the LoadLibrary() statement, there is no crash. when i read the js-ctype documentation, they are saying it is needed to create **shim Library** to call function from javascript.

i've **no idea  how to create Shim Library**....!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing a dll to load another dll - I think a cleaner way would be to compile c++ code into a static library and then write a dll in C that refrences that library's functions. That would work well with js-ctypes